# When does the Spark Dataframe saves in Memory ? Is there a difference on when it saves between Spark 2.2 and Spark 3.0 version?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, aws-glue

**Below is my usecase:**

1. Read the input file and transform it as per the logical mappings. Lets call it as ‘new_file_df’
2. Read the existing data from MariaDB Employee Table. Lets call it as ‘table_data_df’
3. Union new_file_df and table_dat_df
4. Do all the necessary transformation(removing the duplicates as per the indexes and having only the latest) which are required for persisting the data to Table1 table. This contains the entire data to load(existing and new). Lets call it as ‘processed_df’
5. Truncate the Employee table in MariaDB.
6. Write the processed_df to Employee table.

**Where is the issue happening:**
Issue is between Step 5 and 6.

**What is the issue:**

During Step 5, the existing data(from Employee) in ‘processed_df’ also will be removed. While Step 6 executes, it will persist only the new data new_file_df(from the input file) to DB.

**Note:** This is perfectly working with Spark v2.2 where processed_df persists entire data(new_file_df and table_dat_df) to DB without doing cache. This is replicated only with Spark 3 and higher version.

**Temporary Solution with Spark 3.0:**
Caching the dataframe before truncating the data in DB table.

Can anyone explain why this behaviour with Spark 3 and above?

Already tried disabling AQE but still not working in Spark 3.

**Expected :** processed_df should have the entire data even after truncating the table in DB.

**Sample Code:**

`new_write_df = spark.read.parquet(output_df_path)`

`employee_df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", xxxxx, .option("dbtable", “Employee”) ).load()`

`processed_df = employee_df.unionByName(new_write_df)`

`new_write_df.count() // 100`

`employee_df.count()  // 500`

`processed_df.count() // 550`

`db = mysql.connector.connect(host=host, port=port, user=user, password=password,database=database)`

`cursor = db.cursor(prepared=True)`

`cursor.execute('''TRUNCATE TABLE Employee ''')`

`new_write_df.count() // 100`

`employee_df.count()  // 0`

`processed_df.count() // 100`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.